# PHP tamaño de PDF

Tags: php, pdf

Intento subir un pdf de 8 mb o más por algún motivo no me deja, cambie el php.ini

```
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; Its value may be 0 to disable the limit. It is ignored if POST data reading
; is disabled through enable_post_data_reading.
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size=12M
```

este es mi codigo

```
if (isset($_POST['subir']))
    {
    $decreto_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['decreto_id']);
    $decreto = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['decreto']);
    $fecha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['fecha']);
    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $temp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $tipo = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $location = 'file/';
    $postMax = ini_get('post_max_size');
    $acceptable = array('application/pdf');
     $fecha=strtotime($fecha);
     $hoy=date('Y',$fecha);


    if (isset($name))
        {
        $name = $hoy . "ad" . $decreto . ".pdf";
        if (move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location . $name))
            {
            $sql = "UPDATE decreto SET pdf='$name' WHERE decreto_id = '$decreto_id'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
            if ($result)
                { ?>    <div class="mensaje" id="mensaje">
        <div class="text-center">
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                <strong>PDF decreto N° <?php echo $decreto_id ?>Subido</strong> Exitosamente
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } }else { ?>
    <div class="mensaje" id="mensaje">
        <div class="text-center">
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                <strong>Error</strong> Seleccione PDF <?php echo $postMax ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } } } ?>
```

FORM

```
 <form action="" method="post" name="submitt" class="form-signin" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label for="file" class="col col-form-label">PDF</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="file" id="file" accept="application/pdf">
                                 <input type="hidden" name="fecha" id="fechaa">
                                <input type="hidden" name="decreto_id" id="decreto_idd">
                                <input type="hidden" name="decreto" id="decretoo">
                                <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="130000" />
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="subir" method="post"><i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i> Subir Decreto</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
</form>
```

Saludos!

Comment: Ya intentaste modificar tambien este parametro  _upload_max_filesize_ en el _php.ini_

Comment: lol solucionado, gracias!

Comment: De nada saludos, te comparto este enlace, donde adicionalmente puedes modificar otros parametros [Archivos](https://clouding.io/kb/aumentar-el-limite-de-upload-en-php/)